# Adjektiv stark oder schwach dekliniert nach Präpositionalbestimmung

Tags: adjective, declension

Wird ein Adjektiv in diesem Fall stark oder schwach dekliniert? Es gibt zwar in diesem Satz das Bestimmungswort *ihrer*, wonach ein Adjektiv schwach dekliniert werden soll, aber der Einschub *im Offenen* kommt dazwischen, und ich bekomme das Gefühl, man muss "von Anfang an" beginnen und stark deklinieren.
Was ist hier richtig?

> Die altertümliche Konstruktion ist fraglich, mit ihrer im Offenen **laufenden** Welle.

oder

> Die altertümliche Konstruktion ist fraglich, mit ihrer im Offenen **laufender** Welle.

Comment: Not an answer because I don't have a rule to refer to, but the "im Offenen" doesn't change anything. "Mit ihrer im Offenen laufenden Welle" is correct. Compare to: "Die Konstruktion mit im Offenen laufender Welle ist besonders gefährlich"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richtig ist:

> Die Konstruktion mit ihrer im Offenen *laufende**n*** Welle ist fraglich. *(gemischte Deklination)*

(Ich habe den Satz ein wenig umgebaut, damit wir eine geläufigere Wort-Reihung haben, und habe »altertümliche« weggelassen, weil dieses Attribut keinerlei Einfluss hat.)

Ausschlaggebend ist das Possessivpronomen »ihrer«, das die gemischte Deklination erzwingt. Würde das Pronomen fehlen, müsste die starke Deklination angewandt werden:

> Die Konstruktion mit im Offenen *laufende**r*** Welle ist fraglich. *(stark)*

Die Beifügung »im Offenen«, die angibt wo die Welle läuft, hat darauf keinen Einfluss:

> Die Konstruktion mit ihrer *laufende**n*** Welle ist fraglich. *(gemischt)*
>   Die Konstruktion mit *laufende**r*** Welle ist fraglich. *(stark)*

---

Die schwache Deklination (die sich in diesem Fall aber nicht von der gemischten unterscheidet) wäre z.B. nach »dieser« angebracht:

> Die Konstruktion mit *dieser* (im Offenen) *laufende**n*** Welle ist fraglich. *(schwache Deklination)*

Die drei Deklinationsformen unterscheiden sich z.B. bei männlichen Substantiven, wenn man Nominativ und Dativ betrachtet:

- Nominativ

  - schwach: Dieser glänzende Löffel ist aus Silber.
  - gemischt: Sein glänzender Löffel ist aus Silber.
  - Stark: Manch glänzender Löffel ist aus Silber.
- Dativ

  - schwach: Mit diesem glänzenden Löffel kann man essen.
  - gemischt: Mit seinem glänzenden Löffel kann man essen.
  - stark: Mit manch glänzendem Löffel kann man essen.

Mehr über die schwache, gemischte und starke Deklination von Adjektiven kannst du hier nachlesen: http://deutschkurs.co.at/grammatik.html